Need connector/client-id information while getting MM2 kafka.connect.mirror based metrics
I am trying to get "ReplicationLatencyAvg" for MM2 replication based on kafka-connect framework. In my MM2 cluster, multiple connectors are created to support multiple source -> 1 destination replication and are working fine and currently using 'ReplicationLatencyAvg' as mentioned here and calculating consumer lag.
The problem is that after mbean parsing, I am not getting any info. for connectors/client IDs, which makes it hard to identify which connector is causing the lag.
sample output-
kafka.connect.mirror,topic=aggr_test RecordCount=354.0,RecordAgeMs=98.0,RecordAgeMsMin=98.0,RecordAgeMsMax=273.0,RecordAgeMsAvg=156.33333333333334,ReplicationLatencyMs=103.0,ReplicationLatencyMsMin=103.0,ReplicationLatencyMax=278.0,ReplicationLatencyAvg=161.66666666666666,ByteRate=25.139806812404675,partition=59 

